# How does ND4J reference native libraries?

Tags: java-native-interface, blas, nd4j

I am currently working on Deeplearning4J for creating neural networks, what continues to perplex me is that how it references native libraries like OpenBLAS for its operations ?

What does it use ? Does it use jniLoader or some other API ? What is now the de facto piece of software that is used nowadays to write JNI programs ?

Also what's more confusing is that the OpenBLAS libraries are different on both Linux and Windows ? Does that mean that the API of the libraries are same ? I don't see how thats possible since native libraries are bound to the platform they are compiled on.

Comment: Hi there - please join our community on Gitter: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j The community and the framework's creators are active there. It does use JNI, among other things.

Comment: @tremstat No one there was interested in telling me how it works, that's why I had to post here. Btw I am already a part of that community.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the backend. We use We use Java's service loader interface that usually delegates to some JNI layer underneath.

Happy to answer more specific questions if you're looking for something in particular.

Hope that makes sense!It depends on the backend. We use We use Java's service loader interface that usually delegates to some JNI layer underneath. Hope that makes sense!